# @ Mentions on Facebook, linking content from my App

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, hyperlink, facebook-apps

I know that there's no API from Facebook for adding @mentions in the post from Apps & that the message_tags are read-only, but how the other Apps on Facebook link content on the messages in their posts?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is representation of OpenGraph [`actions`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/actions/) user performed on [`objects`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/objects/) and [published](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/tutorial/#publish) by applications.

There is a [tutorial](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/tutorial/) and [samples](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/samples/). Read [Key Concepts of OpenGraph](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/keyconcepts/) and/or [OpenGraph documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/) for more detailed information.

Comment: Thanks for revealing this to me, I've been using Facebook for a year only for posting & haven't seen their new API for these OpenGraph functionalities.